# Как защитить общение сервера с клиентом?

Tags: клиент-сервер, защита

Написал приложения сервера и клиента. Сервер отправляет команды игроку, а клиент выполняет их, возвращая результат выполнения. Вот пример их общения:

СЕРВЕР: OpenFile // program.exe

КЛИЕНТ: true

Как быть, если кто-то тоже может написать клиент и общаться с сервером отправляя ему неверные данные?

Answer (score 1):

Уточните, от чего именно вы хотите защитится? Судя по описанию, что-то типа читов с которыми борятся в MMORPG, Dota и т.п, тогда вопрос насколько сильно вы хотите защитится? Самое простое решение сделать "очень секретную функцию".

Например, после установления TCP соединения, сервер шлет случайное число, клиент его хеширует с какой-то солью и отправляет серверу, сервер перепроверяет результат и либо доверяет клиенту, либо нет.
Это очень простая защита, но если слегка поменять алгорим хешированя и запрятать где-то соль, то без ревирс инженеринга оригинально клиента (или сервера) обойти сложно. Но для людей пишущих краки для програм это не проблема.

Тут может быть такая проблема. Кто-то может подделать адрес сервера и запроксировать трафик (MitM), тем самым влезть в вашу сессию и отдавать серверу любые команды.

Если хотите защитится от MitM, то используейте HTTPS с проверкой сертификата сервера на клиентской стороне.